# Limit API request to zoomed bbox

Tags: leaflet, javascript, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am working on a forked OSM/leaflet/overpass API application which has its own max bounds declared

```
var mapBounds = { south: 50.8025, west: 0.3724, north: 50.8785, east: 0.5290 };
var LBounds = L.latLngBounds([mapBounds.south, mapBounds.west], [mapBounds.north, mapBounds.east]);
```

followed by

```
var map = new L.map('map', {
    maxBounds: LBounds.pad(0.5),
    maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0,
    minZoom: 10,
    maxZoom: 20,
...
```

The query to Overpass API is done via Nominatim

```
geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({
    geocodingQueryParams: {
        bounded: 1,
        viewbox: [mapBounds.west, mapBounds.south, mapBounds.east, mapBounds.north].join(',')
    }
})
```

I have set the mapBounds to allow world view

```
var mapBounds = { south: -90, west: -180, north: 90, east: 180 };
```

and then do something like

```
var mapBounds='bbox=' + map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
```

in order to restrict Overpass API requests to the current viewport only
I couldn't make it work yet.

Comment: And how do your current Overpass API queries look like?

Comment: Hi Ivan, it builds the lookup with Nominatim:  geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({
 geocodingQueryParams: {
  bounded: 1,
  viewbox: [mapBounds.west, mapBounds.south, mapBounds.east, mapBounds.north].join(',')
 }
})

Comment: Please edit your own question to include that information in the question body.